# Web Service sending information to mobile client

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, sockets, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I am looking to make an web application that allows to PUT ,GET etc from the client to the server. That is easy.  However, if a certain event occurs on the serverside I would like to send information to the client. My clients will be mobile devices. I decided to use asp.net webapi.  How should I handle sending information to the client.  Should I use tcp sockets?  What if the event occurs, and I need to send a json to the client, however the client has the application in suspended state. Can I buffer the messages and send it at the next socket connection?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of trying **WebSockets?**. Since they are HTTP, you will not have much problems with things like firewalls. While its original intent was to be used in browsers, there seems to be libraries floating around for objective-c though I have not used any of them my self. One such library http://corner.squareup.com/2012/02/socketrocket-websockets.html

Comment: This is a piece to the puzzle. Indeed WebSockets seem like a good idea. Lets say I have an mobile application that connects to a server whenever it becomes active. Now, lets say a server event occurs and I send that event to the mobile device via the websocket. That makes sense. What if a server event occurs however the device is off.  Is it good practice to store it to a queue that is associated with that device somehow. Than if the user comes back, it sends the commands in the queue?

Comment: Good point, you will need another interface to complement the websockets. As you have mentioned, you could use websockets when the device is up, but have a different interface to query for the messages (which would be stored in storage) generated while its offline. There should be a mechanism to track what messages are already displayed though. In you case, tracking may best be done at client side. For example, at client side, you may store last successfully received message# and then use the second interface (one that delivers stored messages) to query all messages generated since then